# MySQL Show Events in Logical Order

Tags: mysql, sql, date

looking to organize the following dates (assuming today is August 24, 2012):

> December 1, 2012
>   November 1, 2012
>   June 1, 2012
>   June 30, 2012

In the following way:

> November 1, 2012
>   December 1, 2012
>   June 30, 2012
>   June 1, 2012

This is such a way that it shows the events that have NOT yet happened **first**, and from soonest to furthest away, then show past events, from closest to farthest.

You can assume the table structure is:

```
ID   name    event_date
1    Test    1351742400  # All dates are Unix Time
2    Test2   1354338000
```

Comment: If you're showing past events from closest to farthest, surely June 30th should come *before* June 1st?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, name, event_date
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY event_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - event_date)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1c1c/1)

Comment: Wow, thanks man! Excellent code, and awesome website :D Thanks!! I will mark as accepted when it lets me :)